# gRPC client in C# to gRPC server in Go async vs non-async

Tags: c#, go, grpc

I have a gRPC Server written in Go. It works well with a client also written in Go. I tried to write another client in C#.

When using the generated Async method the context on the server side is cancelled after a successful call to the server side implementation and the client is stuck on the line awaiting the result. Behavior does not change whether passing a deadline or a CancellationToken

Everything works as expected when using the non async method. I'm on .NET 6 Windows projects.

Anyone experienced the same and has a solution?

Working code:

```
client.NewCall( new CallRequest { Title = notification.Title }, deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds( 5 ), cancellationToken: cancellationToken );
```

Non-Working code:

```
await client.NewCallAsync( new CallRequest { Title = notification.Title }, deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds( 5 ), cancellationToken: cancellationToken );
```

Comment: If it's truly a problem with the server side (sounds like a bug) then maybe wrap the sync call in a Task.Run, if you're willing to use up a thread.  It's a hack and I normally wouldn't recommend it but it sounds like maybe the only work-around.

Comment: the only difference in behavior between sync and async invocation will be on the client side. Whether you used sync or async api on the client is completely invisible to the Go server so it would be very very weird if the problem was on the server. I suspect the problem could actually be with the code that executes the client side snippets you provided, since from the gRPC library's perspective the behavior of sync and async should really be identical. Is the problem with you synchronization context maybe?

Comment: Have you tried `await client.NewCallAsync( new CallRequest { Title = notification.Title }, deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds( 5 ), cancellationToken: cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);`? If that helps, the problem is likely in the threading model in your client side app. Also, you don't mention if you're using the Grpc.Net.Client implementations of gRPC C# or if you're using Grpc.Core.